# Improving speed of a fine-tuned Tesseract 4 tessdata file

Tags: tesseract

I am using a fine-tuned traineddata file (from tessdata_best). But its' speed is lot slower than tessdata (legacy+LSTM) or tessdata_fast.

Now, is there any way to make the fine-tuned traineddata file faster, by sacrificing slight accuracy? Can we possibly reduce some of the layers of LSTM model?
Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert the existing eng.traineddata file from a tesseract_best model to a tesseract_fast model by :

```
combine_tessdata -c <disk-location/of/current/eng.traineddata>
```

Refer to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/dFSia-Zd_1s) thread for more details